# How can we access the pylint messages in lint.run object?

Tags: python, automated-tests, pylint

Similar to how we access the pylint score using lint.run in the following way:

```
pylint_obj = lint.Run(args,reporter=reporter, do_exit=False) 
pylint_obj. linter.stats['global_note'] <- This is the score
```

Is there any variable which stores pylint messages like these:

```
status.py:348:4: W0612: Unused variable 'foo' (unused-variable)
status.py:373:4: W0612: Unused variable 'step_source_address' (unused-variable)
status.py:429:4: W0612: Unused variable 'range_status_destin' (unused-variable)
status.py:18:0: R0915: Too many statements (103/80) (too-many-statements)
status.py:524:0: R0913: Too many arguments (10/8) (too-many-arguments)
status.py:524:0: R0914: Too many local variables (34/15) (too-many-locals)
```

I need to access the string messages and perform further operations

Answer (score 0):

There's a `CollectingReporter` class in `pylint` itself:

```
from pylint import lint
from pylint.reporters import CollectingReporter


reporter = CollectingReporter()
pylint_obj = lint.Run([__file__], reporter=reporter, do_exit=False)
print(reporter.messages)
```

prints out

```
[Message(msg_id='C0114', symbol='missing-module-docstring', msg='Missing module docstring', C='C', category='convention', confidence=Confidence(name='HIGH', description='No false positive possible.'), abspath='/Users/akx/build/so-misc/aa.py', path='aa.py', module='aa', obj='', line=1, column=0, end_line=None, end_column=None)]
```

(and nothing else since `CollectingReporter` doesn't print out things itself).